# Word Occurrences Script

Tags: awk

I'm putting together a script that will the count the occurrences of words in text documents.

```
{
        $0 = tolower($0)
        for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ )
        freq[$i]++
}
BEGIN { printf "%-20s %-6s\n", "Word", "Count"}
END {
sort = "sort -k 2nr"
for (word in freq)
        printf "%-20s %-6s\n", word, freq[word] | sort
close(sort)
}
```

It works fine so far, but I'd like to make a couple tweaks/additions:

1. I'm having a hard time displaying the array index number, tried freq[$i] which just spit 0's back at me
2. Is there any way to eliminate the whitespace (spaces) from the word count?

Comment: Can you give some example in input and output? PS `end` and `end.` will be listed as two separate words.  You should remove `.?,"` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to code an own loop to scan the fields, just set `RS` to make each word an own record: E.g. `RS=[^A-Za-z]` will treat every string not completely being built from uppercase and lowercase letters as record separator.

```
$ echo 'Hello world! I am happy123...' | awk 'BEGIN{RS="[^A-Za-z]+"}$0'
Hello
world
I
am
happy
```

The single `$0` matches nonempty lines.

Maybe you want to allow digits in words.. just adapt `RS` to your needs.

So what's left?

Transform to lowercase, count, print sorted results.

File `wfreq.awk`:

```
BEGIN { RS="[^A-Za-z]+" }
$0 { counts[tolower($0)]++ }
END{
        printf "%-20s %6s\n", "Word", "Count"
        sort = "sort -k 2nr"
        for(word in counts)
                printf "%-20s %6s\n",word,counts[word] | sort
        close(sort)
}
```

Example run (only top 10 lines of output for not spamming the answer):

```
$ awk -f wfreq.awk /etc/motd | head
Word                  Count
the                       5
debian                    3
linux                     3
are                       2
bpo                       2
gnu                       2
in                        2
with                      2
absolutely                1
```

But now for something not really completely different...

To sort by a different field, just adapt the `sort = "sort ..."` options.

I don't use `asort()` because not every `awk` has this extension.

File `wfreq2.awk`:

```
BEGIN { RS="[^A-Za-z]+" }
$0 { counts[tolower($0)]++ }
END{
        printf "%-20s %6s\n", "Word", "Count"
        sort = "sort -k 1"
        for(word in counts)
                printf "%-20s %6s\n",word,counts[word] | sort
        close(sort)
}
```

Example run (only top 10 lines of output for not spamming the answer):

```
$ awk -f wfreq2.awk /etc/motd | head
Word                  Count
absolutely                1
amd                       1
applicable                1
are                       2
bpo                       2
by                        1
comes                     1
copyright                 1
darkstar                  1
```

Comment: That helps, Yeti. If I want to sort the counter array by the index number, how would I go about that (instead of sorting by the count #). Output would display index, word, then count.

Comment: I do not understand "sort the counter array by the index number" because the counter array is indexed by lowercased words. And what would you expect by sorting by an index number? Getting the words in the order of their first occurance?

Comment: I didn't do a good job of explaining. If I wanted to sort the array by the word itself (alphabetically). Ex. Index - 1     Word - a     Count 5. Headers only appear on first line. I can sort the array by the index number and the frequency, but not the word itself.